# Convert &[f32] to Vec<f32> in rust without memory copy

Tags: rust, memory

My question was about how I could assign `&[f32]` to a previously declared vector of `f32` without the need to use the `to_vec()` function which I understand performs memory copying.

I have this vector defined:

```
let mut vec = vec![0.0; 5];
for i in 0..5 {
   vec.push(i);
}
```

In the code I receive bytes &[u8] that are reconverted to &[f32] and I would like to assign it to the variable declared in this way:

```
let len = data.len();
let ptr = data.as_ptr() as *const f32;
vec = unsafe { std::slice::from_raw_parts(ptr, len / 4)}.to_vec();
```

In this case I use `to_vec()`, but is there any way to do it without making memory copy of the `&[f32]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do this conversion, you must satisfy the invariants of [`Vec::from_raw_parts`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.from_raw_parts).

Notably, you must *own* the allocation (which means nothing else in the program is expecting to ever use this allocation again), the allocation must have been created using the global allocator, the pointer must point to the start of that allocation, `f32` must have the same alignment as whatever type the allocation was created with, and so on.

If you cannot satisfy these invariants, then no, you cannot do this.

The fact that you have a `&[f32]` means you are borrowing the slice from some other value, which means this code almost certainly *does not* semantically own the allocation and therefore converting it to `Vec` directly would be undefined behavior.

Even if you were given an owned `Vec<u8>`, this would be unsound as `u8` does not have the same alignment as `f32`.